# EmberJs: How to resolve Promise Many Array?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i'm really new on Ember and still figuring things out. So i'm sorry for the beginner question.

Hi have a one-to-many relation in my models like:

```js
import Model, { attr, hasMany } from '@ember-data/model';

export default class EventModel extends Model {
  @attr field_1;
  @attr field_2;
  @attr field_n;

  @hasMany('comment') comments;
}
```

and

```js
import Model, { attr, belongsTo } from '@ember-data/model';

export default class CommentModel extends Model {
  @attr field_1;
  @attr field_2;
  @attr field_n;

  @belongsTo('event') event;
}
```

The classic "An article has many comments thing"...

Everything goes well on my template when I'm getting Event data, but when I try to get its related comments, Ember gives me a Promise: `<DS.PromiseManyArray:ember219>`

All my attemps on resolve the promise failed. How can I resolve that?

**EDIT!**

The problem I was facing were related to using the wrong helper.
I was trying to iterate through the comments using `each-in` helper. When I changed it to `each` helper it worked like a charm.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can follow. What is preventing you from `await`ing it?

Comment: It acts like a promise. Use .then

Comment: Hi, the thing is i'm inside a template like {{@event.comments}}